# Momentsymbol over a letter

Tags: symbols

I want to create a curved arrow over a letter as a symbol for the moment over the letter. Like in this picture:
[image: moment over c]

I tried using `\curvedarrowleft{C}` but it didn't have that kind of functionality.

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53206/various-arrow-shapes-above-letters).

Answer (score 10):

`\curvedarrowleft` is a typo, I believe; try `\curvearrowleft` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for '\curvearrowleft' macro
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\overset' macro

\begin{document}
$\overset{\curvearrowleft}{C}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, it was the \overset{}{} command I needed, thanks! The typo was just in the question :)

Answer (score 6):

Comparing to Mico's excellent answer, the use of a stack allows for the gap between letter and moment arrow to be simply set with the use of an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}  % for '\curvearrowleft' macro
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\overset' macro
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\curvearrowleft}{C}$
vs.\@
$\stackon{C}{\scriptstyle\curvearrowleft}~ 
\stackon[2pt]{C}{\scriptstyle\curvearrowleft}~
\stackon[1pt]{C}{\scriptstyle\curvearrowleft}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user126131 You could also consider making the moment arrow slightly smaller, by using `\scriptscriptstyle` instead of `\scriptstyle`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also load the packages `stackrel` and `amssymb` to your preamble, and then where you want the symbol you can use `\stackrel{\curvearrowleft}{C}`. Also note it is **curve**arrowleft, not **curved**arrowleft. Here's an example

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  

You symbol is $\stackrel{\curvearrowleft}{C}$  
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\stackrel` produces a math relation and should not be used for an ordinary symbol. Better use `\overset` from `amsmath`.

Comment: A downside of using `\stackrel` in this context is that the letter `C` will *not* be typeset on the baseline.