# Over curved arrow in description of trigonometric arc?

Tags: math-mode

How can I write thing like this in latex?

[image: trigonometric arc]

Comment: Aren't arcs usually denoted by an overset parenthesis?

Comment: In my country, it is the case.

Comment: I think it denotes an oriented arc.

Comment: Please check this answer [Various arrow shapes above letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53206/various-arrow-shapes-above-letters), too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could draw the curved arrow with Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\curvearrowed@[3]
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[inner sep=.05ex](a){\kern-.25ex#3\kern-.05ex};
      \draw[arrows={-Latex[#1]},line width=#2]
        (a.north west) to[bend left=45] (a.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\newcommand\curvearrowed[1]
  {%
    \relax
    \ifmmode
      \mathchoice
        {\curvearrowed@{}{.4pt}{$\displaystyle #1$}}
        {\curvearrowed@{}{.4pt}{$\textstyle #1$}}
        {\curvearrowed@{scale=.8}{.325pt}{$\scriptstyle #1$}}
        {\curvearrowed@{scale=.7}{.25pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle #1$}}%
    \else
      \curvearrowed@{}{.4pt}{#1}%
    \fi
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
$\curvearrowed{AB}_{\curvearrowed{AM}_{\curvearrowed{AM}}}$
\curvearrowed{AB}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect :-). My sincere compliments.