# Extensible \vec instead of \overrightarrow

Tags: arrows, vector, kpfonts

Instead of changing to `\overrightarrow{}`, which uses a usual extensible arrow and puts it above the argument, I would like to get an extensible `\vec{}` symbol. My intention is to obtain a new command `\vect{}`, for instance, which is exactly the same as `\overrightarrow{}` but the head is the `\vec` symbol (and the extensible part is done with the aproppiate “`\relbar`s”, which I don't know).

In my case I'm using `kpfonts` package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\newcommand*{\vv}[1]{\vec{\mkern0mu#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
    \vec u,\ \vv u,\ \vv{OA},\ \vv{BC},\ \overrightarrow{AB}
\]
\end{document}
```

I defined the `\vv{}` command because the usual `\vec` gives you a misaligned arrow.

[image]

**EDIT:**
As @GonzaloMedina pointed, there exists the `esvect` package. But, in my opinion, it doesn't provide any arrow with a head matching the style of `kpfonts`.

Comment: To make that clear: you want an extensible `\overrightarrow` with a smaller arrow tip?

Comment: @mafp More or less. That would be a cool step forward. But the last intention is not to get an *smaller arrow tip* but the *`\vec` arrow tip*.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44017/dot-notation-for-derivative-of-a-vector/44071#44071) could also be relevant

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here I introduce `\xshlongvec` that takes an optional and mandatory argument.  The mandatory is the text over which to lay the `\vec`.  The optional is a number which represents the rightward kern (in points) applied to the vec arrow, since as the OP points out, the kerning of `\vec` is not the best.

In this MWE, I use the `kpfonts` mentioned by the OP.  I first give the unaltered `\vec` followed by two instances of `\xshlongvec`.  The one flaw that I note is that the left end of the arrow is not slanted like `\vec`, but is square as the result of being created by a `\rule`.

Thanks to Phillipe for pointing out a deficiency in the original answer, since repaired.

```latex
    \documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{kpfonts}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \newlength\shlength
    \newcommand\xshlongvec[2][0]{\setlength\shlength{#1pt}%
      \stackengine{-5.6pt}{$#2$}{\smash{$\kern\shlength%
        \stackengine{7.55pt}{$\mathchar"017E$}%
          {\rule{\widthof{$#2$}}{.57pt}\kern.4pt}{O}{r}{F}{F}{L}\kern-\shlength$}}%
          {O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
    \begin{document}
    \centering
    \[ \vec{A} \quad \xshlongvec[1]{ABC} \quad \xshlongvec[1]{xyz} \xshlongvec{\Omega M} \]
    \end{document}
```

[image: a screen capture of the output includes A, ABC, xyz, and ΩM]

---

This EDITED solution below works across math styles, by using the `scalerel` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\shlength
\newcommand\xshlongvec[2][0]{\ThisStyle{\setlength\shlength{#1\LMpt}%
  \stackengine{-5.6\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#2$}{\smash{$\kern\shlength%
    \stackengine{\dimexpr 1.3pt+6.25\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle\mathchar"017E$}%
      {\rule{\widthof{$\SavedStyle#2$}}{\dimexpr.1pt+.5\LMpt}\kern.4\LMpt}{O}{r}{F}{F}{L}\kern-\shlength$}}%
      {O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}
\begin{document}
\centering
\[ \vec{A} \quad \xshlongvec[1]{ABC} \quad \xshlongvec[1]{xyz} \quad \xshlongvec{\Omega M} \]
\[ \scriptstyle \vec{A} \quad \xshlongvec[1]{ABC} \quad \xshlongvec[1]{xyz} \quad \xshlongvec{\Omega M}\]
\[ \scriptscriptstyle \vec{A} \quad \xshlongvec[1]{ABC} \quad \xshlongvec[1]{xyz} \quad \xshlongvec{\Omega M} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't check it right now since I don't have MacTeX installed and I don't have enough time now. But it looks perfect. By the way, a question I have: what is the correct way of working: `\vec{A}` or `\vec{\mkern0mu A}`. Is that a bug?

Comment: @Manuel I'm not sure I understand your question.  In the definition of `\xshlongvec`, I have the letters `pt` which forces the optional argument number to be converted to a length in `pt`s.  That is later paired with a `\kern`.  If you removed the letters `pt` from the definition, then you would instead attach the kerning units to your optional argument.  If you wanted those kerning units to be in `mu`s then the `\kern` would have to be changed to a `\mkern`.

Comment: Sorry, I explained quite bad. I'm not talking about `\xshlongvec`, as I said, I have no option to try and see it now. I'm referring to the `\vv`command I defined in the question: *I defined the \vv{} command because the usual \vec gives you a misaligned arrow*. Is THAT a bug, or is it just me that see things “wrong”?

Comment: @Manuel I don't know for sure if its a "bug", but I agree with you that `\vec` does not always put the arrow where I want it.  I think the problem is compounded when you change fonts, because (I'm believing) that the arrow adjustment done by `\vec` is not font-dependent.  Thus, I'm guessing that `\vec` will do even worse with a changed font than with the standard font.  For this reason, I too put the kerning code into `\xshlongvec`, and left it as an optional argument,

Answer (score 17):

The `\vec` command uses `\mathchar"017E` as the arrow, while `\overrightarrow` uses `\mathchar"3221`. Both look like scaled versions of each other to me. So we can replicate `\overrightarrow` with the arrow tip of `\vec`. I propose two versions, a LaTeX one, and one following the `amsmath` route. For the `amsmath` version I give another variant that scales the minus horizontally to make it thinner.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\newcommand*{\vv}[1]{\vec{\mkern0mu#1}}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{%
  \vbox{\m@th \ialign {##\crcr
  \vectfill\crcr\noalign{\kern-\p@ \nointerlineskip}
  $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}
\def\vectfill{%
  $\m@th\smash-\mkern-7mu%
  \cleaders\hbox{$\mkern-2mu\smash-\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
  \mkern-7mu\raisebox{-3.81pt}[\p@][\p@]{$\mathord\mathchar"017E$}$}

\newcommand{\amsvect}{%
  \mathpalette {\overarrow@\vectfill@}}
\def\vectfill@{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar{\raisebox{-3.81pt}[\p@][\p@]{$\mathord\mathchar"017E$}}}

\newcommand{\amsvectb}{%
  \mathpalette {\overarrow@\vectfillb@}}
\newcommand{\vecbar}{%
  \scalebox{0.8}{$\relbar$}}
\def\vectfillb@{\arrowfill@\vecbar\vecbar{\raisebox{-4.35pt}[\p@][\p@]{$\mathord\mathchar"017E$}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \mathchar"017E, \mathchar"3221\\
  \vec u,\ \vv u,\ \vv{OA},\ \vv{BC},\ \overrightarrow{AB} \\
  \vect{u}, \vect{OA}, \vect{BC}, \vect{AB}\\
  \amsvect{u}, \amsvect{OA}, \amsvect{BC}, \amsvect{AB}\\
  \amsvectb{u}, \amsvectb{OA}, \amsvectb{BC}, \amsvectb{AB}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Note that this kind of building extensible accents with minus signs and short arrows shows the typical LaTeX weakness that those accents render oddly on certain resolutions. The raise parameter `-3.81pt` is the best approximation I found to mitigate this problem. You might want to fiddle with it to get better results. Also, the third variant with scaled minus has yet another parameter (the `0.8` scaling factor) that probably needs fine-tuning.

The vertical space between the arrows and the letters is governed by the use of `\overarrow@` from `amsmath`, so the space you get is the same as for `\overrightarrow`. If we want it a little lower, we make a new version of `\overarrow@` and use that in `\amsvect` and `\amsvectb`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\my@overarrow@#1#2#3{\vbox{\ialign{##\crcr #1#2\crcr \noalign{\kern-\p@\nointerlineskip}$\m@th \hfil #2#3\hfil $\crcr}}}

\newcommand{\amsvect}{%
  \mathpalette {\my@overarrow@\vectfill@}}
\def\vectfill@{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar{\raisebox{-3.81pt}[\p@][\p@]{$\mathord\mathchar"017E$}}}

\newcommand{\amsvectb}{%
  \mathpalette {\my@overarrow@\vectfillb@}}
\newcommand{\vecbar}{%
  \scalebox{0.8}{$\relbar$}}
\def\vectfillb@{\arrowfill@\vecbar\vecbar{\raisebox{-4.35pt}[\p@][\p@]{$\mathord\mathchar"017E$}}}
\makeatother
```

The magic number here is the `\kern-\p@` in `\my@overarrow`, which pushes the arrow one point deeper. Again, this is open for fine tuning. Note that this is the same value that is already used in `\vect`.

Comment: Well, that's an improvement, but as you say (1) that hand approximation is not perfect and (2) the *`\relbars`* used in both solutions are thicker than the tail of the `\vec` arrow. Those two were my main objectives (correct thickness of the *relbars* and correct positioning). I suspect the latter (positioning) is far more difficult. Thank you for your improvementent.

Comment: @Manuel Ad (2): I added a way to reduce the thickness of the minus signs. But the hand tuning problem stays, of course.

Comment: After trying a little I ended with `-4.5pt` which I think adapts better (in the `\amsvectb`). By the way, I would like the `\amsvectb` to be lower (a little nearer to the letters of the argument). After that, if nobody cames up with a better solution I accept your answer.

Comment: @Manuel OK, if this fits better. The real test is probably a high DPI printout, but currently I have no working printer around here.

Comment: +1 Great solution. I wonder why nobody writes a package for longer arrows that mimick native arrows.

Comment: One question though.  It seems that this modified long vectors are somewhat higher than ordinary short vectors.  Is there any way to lower them down?

Comment: @Pygmalion I extended the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I really like the `esvect` package. If you read the documentation (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/esvect), it tells you that you can select the type of arrow that you want. The default option is

```
\usepackage[d]{esvect}
```

Although you don't need to add the "d" in the preamble.

If you select option "h", then the arrow looks a little more like the one used in `\vec`.

Comment: MWE would be useful here to compare with the above.