# How to typeset a primed vector

Tags: typography, vector

I write a vector with an arrow above the letter using `\vec{p}` and sometimes the vector needs to be primed using `'` (or `^{\prime}`, equivalently).

However, neither

```
\vec{p}'
```

[image]

nor

```
\vec{p'}
```

[image]

looks satisfactory (first option: prime dash overlaps with vector arrow, second option: arrow looks misplaced).

How would one write a primed vector?

Comment: If you're happy to use boldface for a vector, I would recommend `\renewcommand\vec\mathbf` in the pre-amble, and `\vec{p}'` in the document.

Comment: I'd hope to stick with the arrow notation. So far, the best I got is `\vec{p}^{\, \prime}`, but it still doesn't look right. Maybe I'm overthinking this... Possibly decreasing the size of the prime would be an option, while increasing the spacing.

Comment: I think that `\vec{p}^{\,\prime}` looks alright myself; but I suppose it depends on precisely what you want to achieve with it. Do beware overthinking it though.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Priming a vector denoted with the arrow is, as you discovered, not a really good thing to do. You want to prime the letter, not the whole construction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\pvec}[1]{\vec{#1}\mkern2mu\vphantom{#1}}

\begin{document}
$\vec{p}+\pvec{p}'=\pvec{p}''$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Adding a small amount of space in the first option should make it better:

```
{\vec{p}\,}'
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I am currently doing (see my comment above). It still doesn't look perfect to me, but better indeed.

Answer (score 3):

There's a problem I don't get to understand. And it's the fact that if there are multiple atoms inside a `\vec` it gets recolocated. I comment a little bit [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114321/21930).

*Disclaimer*: this is not fully correct (because, for instance, the prime gets recolocated), but the fact that sometimes `\vec{{}<something>}` looks better than `\vec{<something>}` annoys me.

A possible solution is:

```
\let\originalvec\vec 
\renewcommand*\vec[1]{\originalvec{\kern0pt #1}}
```

If that's not enough, you can mix it with egreg's answer

```
 \newcommand*\pvec[1]{\vec{#1}\mkern1mu\vphantom{#1}}
```

Full compilable example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\let\originalvec\vec
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\originalvec{\kern0pt #1}}
\newcommand*\pvec[1]{\vec{#1}\mkern2mu\vphantom{#1}}

\begin{document}
$\vec p + \pvec p' = \pvec p''$

$\vec h = \vec r \times \vec v = \vec r \times \pvec r'$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Appendix G of _The TeXbook_, rule 12 ( the rule for Acc atoms) will explain you the special treatment that nuclei consisting of a single character receive: the accent may be shifted right a bit (depending on information contained in the kerning tables associated with the `\skewchar` of the font of the nucleus) and, more importantly, the superscript and the subscript are positioned _before_ the accent is superimposed. Sorry, I cannot explain better in so few keystrokes...

Answer (score 1):

In this period I have tried various solutions but I am not very convinced and satisfied. I insert some test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

 \newcommand\barbelow[1]{\stackunder[1.2pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.8ex}{.075ex}}}
 \newcommand\barbon[1]{\stackon[0.5pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.9ex}{.1ex}}}
  \newcommand\barbons[1]{\stackon[0.5pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.9ex}{.1ex}}\mkern2mu\vphantom{#1}}
 \newcommand\bvec[1]{\barbon{\vec{u}}}

%%----------------------------------------------------------------
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120029/how-to-typeset-a-primed-vector/253157#253157

 \let\originalvec\vec
 \renewcommand\vec[1]{\originalvec{\kern0pt #1}}
 \newcommand*\pvec[1]{\vec{#1}\mkern2mu\vphantom{#1}}
%%----------------------------------------------------------------
 \newcommand\barbona[1]{\stackon[1.2pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.9ex}{.1ex}}}
 \newcommand\barbonb[1]{\stackon[1pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.9ex}{.1ex}}}
 \newcommand\barbonc[1]{\stackon[0.8pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.9ex}{.1ex}}}
  \newcommand\barbond[1]{\stackon[0.5pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.9ex}{.1ex}}}
%%----------------------------------------------------------------
 \newcommand\barbonsa[1]{\stackon[1.2pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.9ex}{.1ex}}\mkern2mu\vphantom{#1}}
 \newcommand\barbonsb[1]{\stackon[1pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.9ex}{.1ex}}\mkern2mu\vphantom{#1}}
 \newcommand\barbonsc[1]{\stackon[0.8pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.9ex}{.1ex}}\mkern2mu\vphantom{#1}}
 \newcommand\barbonsd[1]{\stackon[0.5pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.9ex}{.1ex}}\mkern2mu\vphantom{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \centering
  \begin{cases}
    \bar{\vec{u}} - \barbon{\vec{u}}\\
    \bar{u}' - \barbon{u}'\\
    \bar{\vec{u}}' - \barbon{\vec{u}}' - \barbon{\pvec{u}}' - \tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$\barbons{\vec{u}}'$}\\
    \bar{C} - \barbon{C}\\
    \bvec{u}\\
    \pvec{a}+\pvec{b}+\pvec{t}+\pvec{u}\\
    \barbon{\pvec{a}}+\barbon{\pvec{b}}+\barbon{\pvec{t}}+\barbon{\pvec{u}}\\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{.50\textwidth}
    \begin{equation*}
      \centering
      \begin{cases}
        \tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$\bar{u}$}\\
        \tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$\barbona{\vec{u}}'$}\\
        \tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$\barbonb{\vec{u}}'$}\\
        \tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$\barbonc{\pvec{u}}'$}\\
        \tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$\barbond{\pvec{u}}'$}\\
      \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.50\textwidth}
    \begin{equation*}
      \centering
      \begin{cases}
        \tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$\bar{u}$}\\
        \tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$\barbonsa{\vec{u}}'$}\\
        \tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$\barbonsb{\vec{u}}'$}\\
        \tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$\barbonsc{\vec{u}}'$}\\
        \tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$\barbonsd{\vec{u}}'$}\\
      \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Someone raised this old (but good) question, so I might as well mention an alternative.  You can use ISO-style bold italic vectors instead of an arrow.

In PDFLaTeX, you can do this with the `isomath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, isomath, bm}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\[ a \cdot \vectorsym{p}' \times \vectorsym{p}'' \]
\end{document}
```

[image: isomath sample]

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you would use `unicode-math`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\vectorsym[1]{\symbfit{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[ a \cdot \vectorsym{p}' \times \vectorsym{p}'' \]
\end{document}
```

[image: latin modern math sample]

If you want a bolder prime symbol to match the vector symbol, you can define

```
\newcommand\boldprime{\boldsymbol{'}}
```

For this to work in `unicode-math`, you must load a math font that comes in bold, or `\setmathfont` with .`[version=bold]`.