# Vector arrow running into brackets

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

This looks really horrible when I typeset it in Plain TeX:

```
$$[\vec r]$$
\bye
```

The vector arrow bleeds into the bracket on the right, it's not pretty at all. Is there a standard fix for this sort of thing?

Things like `$(\vec r)$` are a bit better because of the curve on the parens, but not by much.

Comment: It's not a standard fix, but the `\xvec` macro here might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44017/dot-notation-for-derivative-of-a-vector/44071#44071
(There's an example of how a vector *r* looks.)

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the cases where some manual intervention is necessary:

```
$$[\vec r\,]$$
\bye
```

[image]

Quoting from the TeXbook (page 169):

> Besides these cases, you will occasionally encounter formulas in which
>   the symbols are bunched up too tightly, or where too much white space
>   appears, because of certain unlucky combinations of shapes. It's usually
>   impossible to anticipate optical glitches like this until you see the first
>   proofs of what you have typed; then you get to use your judgment about how
>   to add finishing touches that provide extra beauty, clarity, and finesse.
>   A tastefully applied `\,` or `\!` will open things up or close things
>   together so that the reader won't be distracted from the mathematical
>   significance of the formula.