# Extensible leftarrow accent above math symbols

Tags: arrows, accents

How can I get a left arrow as a math accent to go over single symbols and groups of symbols, in such a way that:

- the left arrows over a single character and multiple characters have the same heaviness; and
- the left arrow over a single character is not overly long?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{extarrows}

\linespread{1.1} % just to display output here more clearly

\newcommand{\reverse}[1]{\accentset{\leftarrow}{#1}}
\newcommand{\xreverse}[1]{\accentset{\xlongleftarrow{}}{#1}}
\newcommand{\longreverse}[1]{\overleftarrow{#1}}

\begin{document}

Accent single character with left arrow:

\smallskip

$\reverse{\sigma}$ \quad Arrow too short, too light, too small?

$\longreverse{\sigma}$ \quad Arrow too long and heavy!

\medskip

Accent multiple characters with left arrow:

\smallskip

$\xreverse{\sigma \ast \tau}$ \quad Use \verb!\xreverse!: arrow definitely too short. 

$\longreverse{\sigma \ast \tau}$ \quad Use \verb!\longreverse!: arrow long enough, but perhaps too heavy?

\bigskip

Want to use  better arrows in the alternative to \dots
\[(\sigma \ast \tau)^{\leftarrow} \simeq \reverse{\tau} \ast \reverse{\sigma}
\]
\dots that instead puts the long left arrow over the whole group of 3 symbols:

\begin{itemize}

\item $\longreverse{\sigma \ast \tau} \simeq \reverse{\tau} \ast \reverse{\sigma}$ \quad Use \verb!\longreverse! on left, \verb!\reverse! on right.

\item $\longreverse{\sigma \ast \tau} \simeq \longreverse{\tau} \ast \longreverse{\sigma}$ \quad Use \verb!\longreverse! for all.

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: leftarrow accents]

I'd strongly prefer a method that avoids using TikZ or other drawing methods. And I need a method that will be relatively robust when a different font family (e.g., `lucidabr`, `mathtimepro2`) is used insstead of `newtx`. also when `unicode-math` is used along with a math font requiring `xelatex`.

I am aware of [Configurable and Extensible Accents (Arrows, Dots, Vectors)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208162/configurable-and-extensible-accents-arrows-dots-vectors) and the item [Dashed left arrow over symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114501/dashed-left-arrow-over-symbol/114745#114745) that is referenced by the accepted answer to it.

**Addendum: using `halloween` command `\overscriptleftarrow`**

Following the comment by @GuM, I tried the `\overscriptleftarrow` command from the `halloween` package. This *does* seem to work with all the font families I've tried, no matter whether I'm using `pdflatex` or, together with `unicode-math`, `xelatex`.  For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
%\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\newcommand{\reverse}[1]{\overscriptleftarrow{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\reverse{\sigma \ast \tau} \eqsim \reverse{\tau} \ast \reverse{\sigma}$

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: \overscriptleftarrow from halloween.sty and unicode-math]

Comment: This question seem to solicit primarily opinion-based answers...

Comment: @Werner: I've rephrased the question. The main point is to use same thickness left arrow accents when over multiple characters as over a single character, but without an overly long accent when over a single character.

Comment: Have you tried `\overscriptleftarrow` from the `halloweenmath` package?

Comment: @GuM: Will `halloweenmath` coexist happily with `unicode-math` and such math fonts as TeX Gyre Termes Math and Latin Modern Math?

Comment: `halloweenmath` does seem to work with every document text & math font I trow at it. I do hate to load in another package with so many definitions -- for "scary" symbols (witches, ghosts, broomsticks, etc.) drawn with `pict2e` -- irrelevant to ordinary math usage.

Comment: Indeed, the `halloweenmath` package doesn’t help here, if you use `unicode-math`.  Sorry, I overlooked the last lines of your question.  Please note, however, that I posted just a comment, not an answer! (:-)  As for the problem of loading a package with hundreds of definitions, but using only a couple of them… well, it’s something that one often does when using LaTeX! (;-)  However, had the `\overscriptleftarrow` worked, it would have been easy to extract only the necessary definitions.

Comment: @GuM: `halloween` is working for me under XeLaTeX if I use, say, TeX Gyre Termes or Latin Modern. (See addendum to my original question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `calc` and `adjustbox` packages. You can adjust the thickness of the arrow as well as its height as described below.

[image]

First we define the arrow:

```
\newcommand{\newarrow}{\scalebox{.7}{$\leftarrow$}}
```

Adjusting the `.7` will make the arrow lighter or heavier. Using `1` will give you  the original weight of `\leftarrow`, and will increase the size of the arrowhead.

Next we clip off the body of the arrow using the `\clipbox` command from the `adjustbox` package. (Actually it's from the `trimclip` package which is part of `adjustbox`.) What remains is `.3em` of the arrow: mostly just the arrowhead.

After that we scale the arrow body so that the head and body together make up the width of the symbols beneath the arrow. (Actually we clip `.1em` from the right end because there's some white space there.)

After that we place the reassembled arrow over the symbols using `raise` and `rlap` keys from the `adjustbox` package. If you want to adjust the height of the arrow, you can replace `raise=\myheight` with `raise=1.2\myheight`, or any scaling factor.

Here is the macro for `\newreverse`:

```
\newcommand{\newreverse}[1]{\settoheight{\myheight}{\ensuremath{#1}}%
\adjustbox{raise=\myheight,rlap}{%
\clipbox*{0 0 {.3em} {1.5\height}}{$\newarrow$}%
\resizebox{\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}-.3em}{\height}{\clipbox*{{.3em} 0 {\width-.1em} {1.1\height}}{$\newarrow$}}%
}%
#1}
```

Note that you must define `\myheight` using `\newlength{\myheight}`. For some reason, the `\adjustbox` command doesn't accept `raise=\heightof{#1}`.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{calc} % for subtracting lengths
\usepackage{adjustbox} % \adjustbox, \clipbox, \scalebox

\newcommand{\newarrow}{\scalebox{.7}{$\leftarrow$}}
\newcommand{\newreverse}[1]{\settoheight{\myheight}{\ensuremath{#1}}%
   \adjustbox{raise=\myheight,rlap}{%
   \clipbox*{0 0 {.3em} {1.5\height}}{$\newarrow$}%
   \resizebox{\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}-.3em}{\height}{\clipbox*{{.3em} 0 {\width-.1em} {1.1\height}}{$\newarrow$}}%
   }#1}

\newlength{\myheight}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $\newreverse{\sigma \ast \tau} \simeq \newreverse{\tau} \ast \newreverse{\sigma}$
\item $\newreverse{\mathit{abcdefghijklmnop}}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect explanation, rigorous and precise. Very good.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastiano. Your comments are always so kind.

Comment: :-) I'm said the truth :-):-). My best regards.

Comment: This method still uses the `accents` package, whose use with `unicode-math` Ulrike Fischer has cautioned against (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507951/why-missing-number-for-blindmathpaper-if-use-accents-sty-blindtext-sty-with-x). In any case, the load order with `accents` is tricky.

Comment: @murray, this method does not use `accents`. I left it in the code for comparison with OPs original attempts (which did use `accents`). I'll upload a new MWE to be more clear.

Comment: @SandyG: Sorry, I didn't read your answer carefully enough. But it does cause what seems to me odd height placement as in `\reverse{g \ast f} \simeq \reverse{f} \ast \reverse{g}`, where the left arrow over the `f` is considerably higher than the one over the `g` -- as does using `\overscriptleftarrow` from the `halloweenmath` package. On the other hand, the shorter length of the left arrow over a single symbol, such as `\sigma`, with your definition seems better than what `\overscriptleftarrow` gives.

Comment: @murray, you're right. Different heights look odd. This happens, e.g., with `\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}`. You can find solutions to this problem in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/478587/125871) and its answers. A quick fix is to use `\reverse{\vphantom{f}g}` for the last `g`. This will fake the height of the `f`.

Comment: @SandyG: neat! That fixes the height issue no matter whose over-arrows are being used -- yours (which I'm adopting) or those from `halloweenmath`. I hadn't known about `\vphantom` (but often use `\phantom`).