# Why missing number for \blindmathpaper if use accents.sty & blindtext.sty with XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, blindtext

Why does loading `accents.sty` together with `blindtext.sty` produce an error at `\blindmathpaper` in the following source, which uses a `unicode-math.sty`?

The error is:

```
./blindmathpaperXeLaTeXError.tex:16: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.16 \blindmathpaper
```

The same error occurs with other OpenType fonts, e.g., TeX Gyre Termes

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% need to load first to avoid \dddot clash
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

Comment: The accents package is from 2006, and even warns about problems with "non standard math encodings". Why do think it would be a good idea to use it together with unicode-math? (A fast test shows that neither \accentset nor \underset actually works).

Comment: It's taking some fine tuning of accents with `\overset` to compensate for the loss of \accentset` from `accents`. (General bservation: age of answers on tex.stackexchange.com becomes a crucial factor!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really minimal example is

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

$\bar{x}$

\end{document}
```

There is a reason why I always insist on first loading packages and then doing setup. Indeed, the “correct” code

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{accents}

\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}

$\bar{x}$

\end{document}
```

works flawlessly.

In your case:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% need to load first to avoid \dddot clash
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\babelfont{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFont={Latin Modern Roman Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the load order here avoids the error?

Comment: @murray I guess it has to do with how `\setmathfont` works; it seems to leave LaTeX in a state that `accents` doesn't like.

Comment: Per comment by @Ulrike Fischer to my question, I'm (reluctantly) abandoning use of the now-aged `accents`package.

Comment: \setmathfont changes the meaning of bar, and as accent tries to redefine \bar based on it current definition this fails.